# Running application as System (without PSTools)

Tags: vb.net, windows

There are some registry keys that are owned by System, and I can't edit them unless I run as System. I want to be able to edit these keys from my VB application. Any tutorials I've found suggest using PSTools, the now deprecated `At` command, or schtasks. PSTools seems great, but its license seems to restrictive (about redistributing). At and schtasks are too messy, and require scheduling delays.

This is related to my previous question. I want to take what I discovered, and implement it via VB.

[Modify audit policy (group policy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506258/modify-audit-policy-group-policy?noredirect=1#comment56772508_34506258)

I also found this, but am getting error 1314. I realized despite running VS2010 "requireAdministrator", and even Running my EXE as Administrator, it still says my username in Task Manager (running as me, not Administrator). I logged in as Administrator, and got Error 5 instead. Even after ensuring I had the rights set, as suggested by this post ([CreateProcessAsUser error 1314](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475577/createprocessasuser-error-1314)), it still gave me Error 5.

[Using a vb.net application running as SYSTEM, how do I start a detached process for each logged on user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188988/using-a-vb-net-application-running-as-system-how-do-i-start-a-detached-process)

I changed the example to "TokenAccessLevels.Read and Duplicate" rather than MaximumAllowed.

```
 If Not DuplicateTokenEx(hToken.DangerousGetHandle,
            TokenAccessLevels.Read & TokenAccessLevels.Duplicate,
            Nothing,
            SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
            TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
            phNewToken) Then
```

I get Error 5 from CreateProcessAsUser. This is while running VS2010 as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.sysinternals.com/tip-run-process-in-system-account-scexe_topic16714.html

This post was the best I could do. Basically, install a service, run it, then delete it. According to the OP, this is his explanation.

> So how does it work?
>
> 1. The & symbol tells cmd.exe to parse treat the text that follows as if it were a new line in a batch file (It basically is a new line
>      delimiter which allows multiple commands to be combined into 1 line)
>
> To break it down: Create Service - sc create -- binPath= "cmd /c start
>   calc" type= own type= interact Start Service net start -- (This could
>   also be done with: sc start --) Delete Service sc delete --
>
> 2. Variables
>
>    - Service Name: --
>    - App to run: calc
>
> Variables:
>
> 3. How it works:
>
> cmd /c - allows us to pass in parameters to cmd (Without this initial
>   part, it will work if you copy & paste in cmd.exe, but not in the Run
>   Dialog. So this fixes it) sc create binPath= - Since cmd.exe does not
>   respond to service commands, when the SCM runs the app in binPath (Reg
>   = ImagePath) then it will terminate it, when not responding in a timely fasion, therefore cmd.exe cannot be used. It has to call
>   something else which in this case is calc.exe sc create type= This one
>   took a while to figure out. The inital problem is the Window Station
>   in which cmd.exe is launched in (which in turn is inherited by
>   calc.exe (its child process)). Luckily after reading Mark's Windows
>   Internals e4, I was able to solve it by specifying the service as
>   being Interactive. (Experimenting, it actually has to be BOTH
>   interactive(256) and own(16) (256|16 = 272) . Basically what this
>   allows is for the windows to run in \WinSta0\Default (The current
>   user's desktop, allowing the window to be displayed.) After some
>   research from being frustrated that sc would not accept type
>   =own|interact, I found out that it allows us to specify it again, and instead of overwriting Type (dword) it bitwise-ORs it (Adds it).
>   Problems Solved! net start - start the service (probably calls
>   StartService) cmd.exe runs with the command line (CL) of start [File]
>   in which start probably calls ShellExecute (Its ashame that MS didn't
>   allow start to specify a SW_* commands (like hide). Although it does
>   allowing us to min/max windows. cmd.exe opens the app/file, the SCM
>   terminates cmd.exe for not responding in a timely fashion to its
>   commands, and the window is now shown to the user. sc delete - Finally
>   we clean up our path by removing the service

For me, this worked.

```
cmd /c sc create -- binPath= "cmd /c start app.exe" type= own type= interact & net start -- & sc delete --
```

Now, I had trouble with getting absolute paths to work. I had to put my .EXE in System32 and SysWOW64, so I didn't have to use an absolute path. According to the site, this is supposed to allow absolute paths to work.

```
cmd /c sc create -- binPath= "cmd /c start  \"\"  \"C:\windows\regedit.exe\" " type= own type= interact & net start -- & sc delete --
```

It never worked for me, as it would hang for some time and never start the app. It should almost instantly complete.